# How to convert R Script to R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is it possible to convert my R script to an R Markdown?
I don't want to get the R Markdown output directly, I know that is possible with `knitr::stitch()` but I didn't get the script itself converted to markdown by that. My script consists of lot of comments and I would directly transform it into a Markdown file if that is possible.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `knitr::spin(hair = "<your-script>.R", knit = FALSE)`. Read the documentation at `?knitr::spin` for information about how to format your comments.